# How can I run port-forward istio-ingressgateway in background?

Tags: kubernetes, kubeflow, istio-gateway

I installed kubeflow manifest follow from [kubeflow/manifasts](https://github.com/kubeflow/manifests).

And I checked istio-ingressgateway work for me.

```
$ kubectl get svc istio-ingressgateway -n istio-system
```

```
NAME                   TYPE       CLUSTER-IP     EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)                                                                      AGE
istio-ingressgateway   NodePort   10.96.89.178   <none>        15021:32680/TCP,80:32075/TCP,443:32334/TCP,31400:30226/TCP,15443:30276/TCP   15m
```

```
$ kubectl port-forward svc/istio-ingressgateway -n istio-system 8080:80
```

```
Forwarding from 127.0.0.1:8080 -> 8080
Forwarding from [::1]:8080 -> 8080
```

This terminal should always be running when I connecting to `8080`.

**What I need help**:

I want this port forwarding to run in the background.

There is no way to run  port-forward in the background??

> env:
>
> - ubuntu 20.04
>
> ```
> $ kubectl version --client && kubeadm version
> ```
>
> ```
> Client Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"22", GitVersion:"v1.22.13", GitCommit:"a43c0904d0de10f92aa3956c74489c45e6453d6e", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2022-08-17T18:28:56Z", GoVersion:"go1.16.15", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}
> kubeadm version: &version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"22", GitVersion:"v1.22.13", GitCommit:"a43c0904d0de10f92aa3956c74489c45e6453d6e", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2022-08-17T18:27:51Z", GoVersion:"go1.16.15", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}
> ```

Comment: To perform kubectl port-forward in background you can append the command with & as `kubectl port-forward pods/my-pod 8080:80 & ` This will print the PID of the process and then send the command to background and you will be able to use the terminal try this and let me know if this work.

Comment: Since it's a NodePort-type service, you should be able to connect to any of your nodes' DNS names or IP addresses, and the mapped port 32075.  The ingress gateway in particular I might expect to be the one thing that's reachable from outside the cluster and you shouldn't need to port-forward it.